# AngularJS animation (show/hide) speed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I've created a show/hide animation on my Angular page.

I've used the standard angular-animate.js library, paired with animate.css. AngularJS core is v1.2.20. Everything is working fine, and I'm using it in several occasions.

When the show/hide functions are called, all kinds of classes are added while it's transitioning from a 'show' to a 'hide' state, so you can create some nice css-animations. The thing is, how can you speed this 'classes-adding/removing-transition-thing' up (or slow it down)?

---

*In case someone is wondering what code I use:*

My directive HTML:

```
<div class="datepicker-panel panel panel-square panel-no-border panel-default m-md ng-hide animated" 
     ng-show="datepicker.show" 
     ng-class="{'fadeIn':datepicker.show, 'fadeOut':!datepicker.show}" 
     ng-controller="DatePicker">
    <!-- Some HTML -->
</div>
```

Paired with the following toggle button:

```
<div class="datepicker-button" ng-click="datepicker.toggle()">
</div>
```

And the toggle logic in some controller:

```
$scope.datepicker   = { 'show' : false };

$scope.datepicker.toggle = function() {
     this.show = !this.show;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at transitions, the AngularJS docs have an example on that:

```
.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
```

which as you might imagine describes a 0.5 seconds lasting transition.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: You're actually right. I just tried by setting the transition to 5s, and the whole classes-adding-stuff also took 5 seconds. Never realized this was CSS-based. Thanks.